# On MVC, clarification on object responsibility needed

Tags: model-view-controller

Suppose, as part of an iphone application, I need to show user a list of some of some objects.

**The model**

- Represents actual objects to be shown
- Brainless data, collection of getters and setters

**The view**

- Displays the list, passes received actions to a controller
- Presentation layer

**The Controller**

- Interprets actions received from the view and takes actions on data
- Sits between the view and data

In this picture, would be be controller's responsibility to persist model to disk, or, should it be a part of Model's logic? Request to do this will come from a controller, but, should the controller know how to save data to disk, or should data know how to save itself to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong.

Model is responsible for all the business logic. Additionally model is not directly aware of database or any other data storage medium. When model is initialized it receives factory for creating DAOs or DataMappers which are the ones responsible for storing and retrieving the informations.

Controller interprets the received information from view , and changes the state of model and view.

View either receives information from a persistent model via observer pattern ( classical MVC ) or request data from models ( Model2 MVC ).

Answer (score 1):

I can see this going both ways. I would think that this logic goes into the model this way the controller is a little cleaner. Also, if you're using this functionality across models and it's mostly consistent e.g `$person->saveData()`, `$user->saveData()` then you could possible extend the base model so it would be inherited by other models and save you from duplicate code.

If this logic is incorporated into the model it would probably be a good idea to make it flexible enough so that the controller can override the persisting of data. So maybe, pass an argument into the model function `$person->save( false )` This `false` would prevent the model from persisting the data but on default would be `true`.